# Xcode cannot locate java runtime

Tags: java, xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I am writing a Kotlin Multiplatform project and everything are compiling fine when I compile it in Android Studio, however when I try to compile it in Xcode I get a compile error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.

Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

I have installed Java and can in a terminal find it so it seems like the problem is in Xcode:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/xxx/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

I have executed kdoctor and it finds no issue with my setup:

```
$ kdoctor
Environment diagnose (to see all details, use -v option):
[✓] Operation System
[✓] Java
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] Xcode
[✓] Cocoapods

Conclusion:
  ✓ Your system is ready for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Development!
```

Comment: I'm guessing that xcode ignores the JAVA_HOME environment variable and likely needs some manual config to tell it where you've installed the jdk

Comment: try [kdoctor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kdoctor)

Comment: Check where your JAVA_HOME is defined. In my case it was in ~/.zshrc, defining it in ~/.zshenv solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem myself by changing the build script in xcode to:

```
JAVA_HOME="/Users/xxx/.sdkman/candidates/java/current" "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
```